# Hiding more than one column based on cell color

Tags: excel, vba

I have a very large spreadsheet with conditional formatting that turns a cell red (color 255) if certain parameters are true. This part is working fine.

My issue is that I am trying to write a macro to hide the entire column and the entire column to the left of it if there is a cell in the first column that has a red cell in it. For example, if column N has a red cell in it, it will hide column N and column M. This inquiry will need to be run for all columns "I:HC" (like I said, it is a giant spreadsheet.) I will be associating this macro with a Form Control Button so that when the button is activated, the columns will hide.

Any ideas would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Getting the logic and requirements for **what** your macro needs to do is the important first step. For posting a question here, the next step is to re-frame your question with the guidelines in creating a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). You'll get all the help you need.

Comment: What version of Excel are you using?  For later versions you can directly access the conditional format colour.  For earlier versions you have to recode the conditions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try checking the `DisplayFormat` like this:

```
Private Sub HideRedFilledColumnPairs()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim lastRow As Long, lastColumn As Long
    Dim r As Long, c As Long

    Set ws = ActiveSheet

    ' get the used range
    lastRow = ws.Cells.Find(What:="*", LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
        SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious).Row
    lastColumn = ws.Cells.Find(What:="*", LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
        SearchOrder:=xlByColumns, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious).Column

    ' loop your columns row by row
    For c = ws.Range("I:I").Column To ws.Range("HC:HC").Column ' or To lastColumn
        For r = 1 To lastRow
            If ws.Cells(r, c).DisplayFormat.Interior.Color = vbRed Then
                ws.Columns(c).EntireColumn.Hidden = True
                ws.Columns(c - 1).EntireColumn.Hidden = True
                Exit For    ' take next column
            End If
        Next r
    Next c

    Set ws = Nothing
End Sub
```